# Edit individual character or word in RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

[image]

Basically in RichEditBox you can paste text and it can automatically format that pasted text according to what you copied.  I am wondering how to set a specific part of the document, such as a word, or sentence, to a specific form of font colour, or font style, or any other properties regarding text.

I cannot find any real documentation on how to do such a thing.

EDIT:

I found:

```
 richEditBox.Document.GetRange(3, 10).CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue;
```

If someone knows something nicer, post please.

Comment: You should look to re-format the data when the user attempts to paste from the clipboard string into the RichTextBox. Or you could re-format teh data on teh Text_Changed event for the RichTextBox??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
richEditBox.Document.GetRange(3, 10).CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dhsw8eb(v=vs.90).aspx